# Check if a vector element exists using std::find?

Tags: c++

I need to know how to check if a element (object) inside a vector exists.

I've heard of std::find but the I don't understand how to use it (even though I've read multiple answered questions here, and on other forums).

```
find(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, const _Ty& _Val)
```

- What are all the parameters?
- What does the function return?

I couldn't find any good posts that explain this (or at least, didn't explain it good enough for me to understand).

---

Example : (this is the return type)

> An iterator to the first element in the range that compares equal to val.
>   If no elements match, the function returns last.

(taken from std::find documentation) This makes no sense at all to me.

---

Examaple of how I would like to use it :

```
if (texts[index]) == does exist)
    do something
else
    do something else
```

---

This is how I'm currently using it, which is wrong.

```
std::vector<Text*>::iterator result;
result = find(texts.begin(), texts.end(), texts.begin() + index);

if (result != texts.end())
    std::cout << "Element removed" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "Element not found in texts, won't remove." << std::endl;
```

It gives me this error : (just parts of it, scroll down if you need the entire error...)

```
error C2679: binary '==': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Text *>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Full error :

```
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\system_error(379): note: could be 'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\system_error(371): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\system_error(363): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\system_error(355): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\exception(341): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t) throw()'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\exception(336): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &) throw()'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\exception(331): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &) throw()'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility(3134): note: while trying to match the argument list '(Text *, const std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Text *>>>)'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility(3153): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::_Find<_InIt,_Ty>(_InIt,_InIt,const _Ty &,std::false_type)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _InIt=Text **,
1>              _Ty=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Text *>>>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility(3162): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::_Find<Text**,_Ty>(_InIt,_InIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _InIt=Text **,
1>              _Ty=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Text *>>>
1>          ]
1>  c:\users\myname\desktop\c++ projects\sfml_game\sfml_game\main.cpp(93): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::find<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Text *>>>,std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Text *>>>>(_InIt,_InIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Text *>>>,
1>              _Ty=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Text *>>>
1>          ]
```

---

**Edit**, updated my code, now looks like this but when I run it, it prints "Could not remove element, it does not exist!".

```
void RemoveText(unsigned int index)
{
    std::vector<Text*>::iterator result;
    result = find(texts.begin(), texts.end(), texts[index]);

    if (result >= texts.end())
        texts.erase(texts.begin() + index); 
    else
        std::cout << "Could not remove element, it does not exist!" << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## This should work

```
std::vector<Text*>::iterator result;
result = find(texts.begin(), texts.end(), thing_I_want);
```

### Explanation of iterators

`texts.begin()` returns an *iterator* which points to the first element in text. Iterators have a special property, that adding a number to them will increment the index they reference.

More clearly, `*(texts.begin())` is the first element of texts. `*(texts.begin() +1`) is the second element of texts. `*(texts.end())` is the last element of texts.

### Explanation of std::find

```
result = std::find(

arg1 // iterator pointing to where we should start searching

arg2 // Iterator pointing to where we should stop searching

arg3 // Thing to search for in container

)
```

It will return another iterator, this one pointing to the element that matched. If you'd like to recover the index, you can do either

```
int index = std::distance(Texts.begin(), result)
```

Or

```
int index = result - Texts.begin()
```

### What went wrong

When you did `index + texts.begin()`, the result of the addition was an iterator, for which there isn't a comparison operation to your text type. That makes sense, because the third argument to `std::find` is what we're looking for, so we (in the worst case) need to compare that to all of the elements in the range we're searching. If we don't have a defined comparison between the thing we're searching for, and the elements of our vector, then there must be no way we can search for it.

Comment: Of what type is arg3? What should I write in "thing_i_want" ?

Comment: You are searching for something, what are you searching for?

Comment: Oh, I think I see - you aren't searching for anything, you just want to see if it exists. The only case where a vector element "doesn't exist" is when index >= vector.size(). Otherwise, there must be something there, even if it is a NULL ptr.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do. I want to check if a specific element is exists inside my vector.

Comment: Added the "updated" version of my code.